# running python from NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js

I'm trying to run this example:

```
//start.js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    py    = spawn('python', ['compute_input.py']),
    data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    dataString = '';

py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  dataString += data.toString();
});
py.stdout.on('end', function(){
  console.log('Sum of numbers=',dataString);
});
py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(data));
py.stdin.end();
```

This is a Python script:

```
## compute_input.py

import sys, json, numpy as np

#Read data from stdin
def read_in():
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    #Since our input would only be having one line, parse our JSON data from that
    return json.loads(lines[0])

def main():
    #get our data as an array from read_in()
    lines = read_in()

    #create a numpy array
    np_lines = np.array(lines)

    #use numpys sum method to find sum of all elements in the array
    lines_sum = np.sum(np_lines)

    #return the sum to the output stream
    print (lines_sum)

#start process
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And when in command prompt I run `node start.js`, I receive output '`Sum of numbers=`', but I expect '`Sum of numbers=45`'.

It seems like Python didn't run. I have numpy installed and using Python 3.

Other users receive correct result, but I don't. What can be the reason?

Comment: Your issue is not reproduced in my environment. I got `Sum of numbers= 45` correctly.

Comment: what can be potential problems?

Comment: umm.... the shell command `echo '[1,2,3,4,5]' | python compute_input.py` outputs `15` correctly? and python filename exactly `compute_input.py`?

Comment: @set0gut1 , yep. compute_input.py same directory as start.js